# VBA - Unintentionally creating an array within an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant, jagged-arrays

Below is the extract of some code I am writing that attempts to compare a range at the beginning of a process (captured in a global array in a sheet activate event) with the same range when the sheet is deactivated.

Here is the activate code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

garr_Agency = Array(Range("rng_Lst_Agencies").Value2) 'rng_Lst_Agencies is a 1D column.

End Sub
```

And here is the deactivate:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

Dim arr_Agency() As Variant
Dim rng_Agency As Range
Dim lng_Agencies As Long
Dim lng_i As Long

Set rng_Agency = Range("rng_Lst_Agencies")

arr_Agency = Array(rng_Agency.Value2)

lng_Agencies = rng_Agency.Cells.Count
lng_i = 1

Do Until lng_i = lng_Agencies + 1
            If arr_Agency(0)(lng_i, 1) <> garr_Agency(0)(lng_i, 1) Then 
*rest of the code*
```

I would have thought I could just use:

```
If arr_Agency(lng_i, 1) <> garr_Agency(lng_i, 1) Then
```

but I get a "Subscript out of range" error.

Why do I need to add the extra "(0)"? From the locals window it looks as if I have created an array within an array somewhere along the line but I don't see how.

Many thanks.

Comment: just leave array(...)  out

Comment: ^ As EvR says. The reason is that VBA will already treat your range object like an array, so when you put it inside the Array() function it is creating an array object and putting another array object inside it.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Also remember that while regular arrays are 0-based, cell arrays are 1-based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting a nested array is because of this line:

```
arr_Agency = Array(rng_Agency.Value2)
```

Do this instead:

```
arr_Agency = rng_Agency.Value2
```

That will create a one dimensional array, because when you assign to a variant its automatically treated as being an array.